# Game Theory - Game tree - Nash equilibria

Tags: game-theory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BceRD.jpg)could you please help me answer this problem?

Two players alternate in
placing dominoes on a 2  3 chess board so as to cover two squares exactly. The first to be unable to place a
domino is the loser. Draw the game tree for this game (you can omit symmetric/rotated moves from the tree,
just as I did in the lectures) and find a subgame-perfect NE. If players are rational, who wins the game, the
first or the second mover?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: What's "a $2$ $3$ chess board"?

Comment: This is how I look at it, Jose Carlos, you can take a look at the picture attached above! I think it is a really easy one, however I would like to have some feedback from the masters!

Comment: Joriki, sorry my bad! it's a 2x3 chessboard!